# How can i create a For cycle to create multiple URL adress (by changing only one piece)?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

this is my code to create a URL link for Yahoo Finance with for a specific company (in this case Microsoft).

```
index = 'MSFT'
url_is = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + index + '/financials?p=' + index
```

How can i create a for cicle for multiple companies with different tickers (for example index = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'V'])

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you’re looking to grab financials data from yahoo finance for multiple symbols, look at [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery).  To get income statement data, you could do the following:  Ticker(‘msft aapl v’).income_statement()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
index = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'V']
for company in index:
    url_is = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + company + '/financials?p=' + company
    print(url_is)
```

If you wanted to store the resulting URLs in a list, just do:

```
my_list = []
for company in index:
    url_is = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + company + '/financials?p=' + company
    my_list.append(url_is)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works very well but i have another question: i need to use                
          urllib.request as ur, does it work on lists?

Comment: Sure - you can just loop through the list, for example with `urllib.request.Request(url_is)`